# Python - UnboundedLocalError

Tags: python

```
import random

def hiLo(userNum, ran, c):
    c = c + 1

    if ran > userNum:
        newNum = input("Higher: ")
        hiLo(int(newNum), ran, c)
    elif ran < userNum:
        newNum = input("Lower: ")
        hiLo(int(newNum), ran, c)
    else:
        print("That's it! That took you", c, "tries!")

def easyLevel():
    choice = input("\nTry and guess the random number(1-10): ")

    if not choice:
        print("You need to make a guess. Try again.")
        easyLevel()
    else:
        choiceNum = int(choice)

    if choiceNum < 1 or choiceNum > 10:
        print("That is out of range. Try again!")
        easyLevel()

    count = 0

    randNum = int(random.random() * 10 + 1)
    hiLo(choiceNum, randNum, count)

#Checks if user inputs are out of range
def checkLevel(level, low, high):

    if level > high or level < low:
        print("That is out of range. Try again!")
        main()

def main():
    print("\n ::: Welcome to the Guessing Game! ::: \n")
    print("1 - Hard(100)   2 - Medium(20)   3 - Easy(10)")
    level = input("Choose what level you would like to play: ")

    if not level:
        print("You need to choose a level. Try again.")
        main()

    level = int(level)

    #check level is out of range
    checkLevel(level, 1, 3);

    if level == 1:
        hiLevel()
    elif level == 2:
        medLevel()
    else:
        easyLevel()

main()
```

The code above is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/Guessing Game/guessing_1.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/Guessing Game/guessing_1.py", line 47, in main
    main()
  File "C:/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/Guessing Game/guessing_1.py", line 59, in main
    easyLevel()
  File "C:/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/Guessing Game/guessing_1.py", line 24, in easyLevel
    if choiceNum < 1 or choiceNum > 10:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'choiceNum' referenced before assignment
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Take a look at line 24. Not sure why it's giving me the error.

Comment: When `choice` is falsey, you don't set `choiceNum`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call easyLevel, if it goes into the if statement instead of the else statement, your `choiceNum` variable is undefined because it is only set in the else statement. You should initialize choiceNum in the beginning or set choiceNum in the if statement as well

```
if not choice:
    print("You need to make a guess. Try again.")
    easyLevel()
    choiceNum = 0 #declare choice num or return 
else:
    choiceNum = int(choice)
```